# string represents date, and reformat it

Tags: c#, string, date

The following case:
There is a string that has this format "2012-02-25 07:53:04"

But in the end, i rather want to end up with this format "25-02-2012 07:53:04"

I think i have 2 options. 1 would be to reformat the string and move it all around, but i dont think this is a clean way of doing this.

A other way that i was thinking about is to save the source string to a date parameter, and then write the date parameter back to a string in a certain date format.
But is this even possible to do ?

Comment: Please note that iso8601 date format (your original string format) have 2 very good properties - does not change from culture to culture and allows simple string comparison to be used for sorting. It also supports timezones if needed. I would strongly recommend not using custom/culture aware formats for any data persistence. Perfectly fine/expected to use culture aware ones for values shown to user.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do this:

```
DateTime.Parse("2012-02-25 07:53:04").ToString("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
```

Keep in mind this isn't culture-aware. And if you do need to store the intermediate result you could do that just as easily:

```
var myDate = DateTime.Parse("2012-02-25 07:53:04");
var myDateFormatted = myDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
```

Lastly, check out [`TryParse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx) if you can't guarantee the input format will always be valid.

Comment: what do you mean with "culture-aware" ? you mean in case the date is stored in a different format, depending on the machine its running on ?

Comment: @Dante1986 No, it means that you're forcing that date format upon **all** cultures. While it may make sense in cultures accustomed to seeing that date style, it may be confusing for others. And in this example the format will not change - it's always going to be `25-02-2012 07:53:04` - but that sounds like exactly what you want.

Comment: @Yuck: Actually, the code you've given *is* slightly culture-aware, in that it will use the current culture's time separator. It's a bad idea to mix up "forced" formats and cultures, IMO - I would almost always recommend using the invariant culture when specifying a custom format string.

Comment: @Yuck: ahaa, i understand. Well its a application to analyze some log XML files for personal use, so in that case i dont need to take culture into account :)

Comment: @Dante1986: I would still encourage you to explicitly specify the expected input format... and actually specify the invariant culture as a matter of good practice. If you're careless about these things in hobby projects, it tends to slip into work code - at least it does for me!

Answer (score 2):

Others have suggested using `Parse` - but I'd recommend using `TryParseExact` or `ParseExact`, also specifying the invariant culture unless you *really* want to use the current culture. For example:

```
string input = "2012-02-25 07:53:04";

DateTime dateTime;
if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(input, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
                            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                            DateTimeStyles.None,
                            out dateTime))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Couldn't parse value");
}
else
{
    string formatted = dateTime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss",
                                         CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    Console.WriteLine("Formatted to: {0}", formatted);
}
```

Alternatively using [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com):

```
string input = "2012-02-25 07:53:04";

// These can be private static readonly fields. They're thread-safe
var inputPattern = LocalDateTimePattern.CreateWithInvariantInfo("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
var outputPattern = LocalDateTimePattern.CreateWithInvariantInfo("dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss");

var parsed = inputPattern.Parse(input);
if (!parsed.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Couldn't parse value");
}
else
{
    string formatted = outputPattern.Format(parsed.Value);
    Console.WriteLine("Formatted to: {0}", formatted);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Parse as DateTime then reformat it. Be careful: **use always an IFormatProvider**!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [custom DateTime format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) to parse and reformat DateTime objects.

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("2012-02-25 07:53:04", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string formattedDated = date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: Given that you know the input format, I'd suggest using ParseExact. Why rely on the current culture's idea of what a date/time looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is quite possible. All you need to do is use `DateTime.Parse` to parse the `string` into a `DateTime` struct and then use `ToString()` to write the date back out to another string with the format you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse this as a date object and then provide the formatting you want when using the date.ToString method:

```
date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
```