# How string format date bind with date picker in wpf c#

Tags: date

I have date like "15/08/2016". and my system date have like yyyy-mm-dd format. I want to my date bind  with date time picker

Comment: Ok. Good luck with that. Since you haven't specified what language you're using, we can't help you...

Comment: i have using c# language

Comment: Possible duplicate of [string represents date, and reformat it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9488819/string-represents-date-and-reformat-it)